# Google recaptcha cookies

Tags: cookies, recaptcha, captcha

I can't seem to find any resources on what exact cookies are set on users when i use Google Recaptcha v3. I am required to notify users what cookies we use, but when i inspect the site it greatly varies from time to time what/how many cookies comes from .google.com domain.

Can somebody help me with a list?

I can see one that is called "NID" is recurring, and sometimes i get one called "1P_JAR". At other times i see up to 7 other cookies from the .google.com domain. Very inconsistent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a complete list either, but I have some ideas on how you could get closer to an answer. These options are in order of preference.

**Option 1:**
You could implement a privacy management solution to handle GDPR and the like. These tools usually scan your sites for cookies and do a fair amount of auto categorization of the cookies that fire on your site. I imagine you will have use cases down the road where you need to know what cookies fire from another vendor. It is basically impossible to track them all down in a manual manner.

**Option 2:**
You could also create an isolated set of pages that has only Google recaptcha V3 on it and no other code that would fire cookies. You can then navigate to Application -> Cookies in the Chrome dev tools and just look at what is fired there as you move between the pages and attempt form submissions. That should give you a pretty good list of the cookies that are fired by the recaptcha and you can just remove duplicates from your list after you have compiled it.

**Option 3:**
I am imagining most of these cookies have to be created client side, so you can see which JS scripts are being loaded from the Google recaptcha and search the contents to see which cookies are created. Search for "cookie" or any other manner in which a cookie can be set through JS. I am guessing the code will be pretty hard to follow and minified though.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have **Google Signals** enabled on your site. Try turning off BOTH **Remarketing** and **Advertising Reporting features** in data collection settings in Google Analytics.

Google Analytics --> Admin --> Property --> Tracking Info --> Data Collection.